# default value for the 2nd argument in Power for pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to match terms in power like `a^b`, including `b=1` case. I know that I can do something like `x_^y_.`, but by looking at the documentation, I didn't find any words saying that the default value of the second argument of power is `1`, so how to understand that `x_^y_.` can match the symbol `x` when `y=1`?

Comment: The pattern `_^1` is equivalent to `_`, so this would not make much sense...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm sorry, but say I have a list `{a, b^2, c^3}` and now I want to apply rules to this list. `b^2` and `c^3` can be matched by powers, and to keep the rules as simple as possible, I want the element `a` to be matched as well, and if you were me, how would you match this element? From practicing, I know that pattern like `x_^y_. ` will match all the elements in the list, but I just don't understand why the default value of y is taken to be 1.

Comment: @MarcoB I agree that the pattern matcher will not try to interpret `a` as `Power[a,1]`, it will instead just take `a` as a `Symbol`. What my problem is I want to match `a`, `b^2`, `c^3` etc consistently with only ONE rule to keep my code simple and then manipulate them afterwards.  With that being said, I find patter like `x_^y_.` works like a charm, but then I have the difficulty in understanding why the default value of `y` is set to be one since the `Power` function does not deal with things like `Power[a,1]` as you have said.

Comment: @MarcoB you can match expression that do not contain explicitly the pattern head. `{a, 2 a, 3 a} /. x_. f[a] :> x` gives `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}` and there is no such thing as `Times[1, a]`.

Comment: @Batracos Can't reproduce your result. You sure that's what you meant? It returns `{a, 2 a, 3 a}` on my end, and `MatchQ[x_. f[a]] /@ {a, 2 a, 3 a}` returns `{False, False, False}`.

Comment: @Y.Du I did misread your question. I see your point now.

Comment: I think it's important to add that `Power[...]` pattern (containing `Optional`) can match expression, which head is not `Power`, due to [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OneIdentity.html) attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `DefaultValues`:

```
DefaultValues[Power]
```

> {HoldPattern[Default[Power, 2]] :> 1}

And, to address some confusion in the comments, notice that the pattern `_^_.` does match `a`:

```
a /. _^_. -> 1
```

> 1

You can also query the default value using [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default):

```
Default[Power, 2]
```

> 1

Comment: @MarcoB I think unfortunately the `*Values` functions are rather un(der)documented.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CarlWoll That's too bad. Thank you for adding the `Default` alternative though.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting gotcha related to the `DefaultValue` for `Power`. Suppose you want to eliminate all odd powers from the polynomial

```
poly = x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4
```

First consider

```
poly /. x^n_ /; OddQ[n] :> g[n]
```

This behaves as expected but, of course, does not match `x` by itself. Now try

```
poly /. x^(n_.) /; OddQ[n] :> g[n]
```

It took me far too long to realise that this output is explained by noting that, with the default value for the second argument of power, the pattern `x^2` is equivalent to the pattern `(x^1)^2`. I'd bet that this will lead to some puzzlement when you try

```
poly /. x^(n_.) /; OddQ[n] :> 0
```

(naively) expecting instead to get `x^2 + x^4` as the result.

Comment: Thank you for your input and sorry for the late reply. This is actually an interesting point that I did not realize. I tried and found that EvenQ would work as expected. The problem is with OddQ. I think it's worthy of posting a new post on this topic.